# Bootstrap,How to make a container-fluid have a height of 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap container-fluid wrapped up in a div, and now i want the container-fluid to have height of 100% regardless of it's content but it seems it only take up the height of it content below is my code

```
Html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container-fluid h-100 test">this is container-fluid
  <div>hello my brother</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

My css

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  padding: 0 0 60px;
  background: blue;

}


.test {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
}

.footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

now i want the yellow div to take up 100% height but it doesn't work as expected.. here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sammyzeal/8ph16n4j/15/)

Comment: 100% is that respect window resolution or to it's parent?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mngdrsw4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving `wrap` a `height:auto` just remove that `height:auto` means that it will maintain it's own height to it childrens, If their are more childs then it will increase it's own height.Just remove that and add `height:100%`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
 
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  padding: 0 0 60px;
  background: blue;

}


.test {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
}

.footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>

    <title>Welcome </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="container-fluid h-100 test">this is container-fluid
      <div>hello my brother</div>
      </div>
      
    </div>

  </body>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="pull-left">my site</p>

      <p class="pull-right">2019</p>
    </div>
  </footer>



</html>
```

Comment: It seems the footer is missing.